# Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or (fontspec) LuaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, windows

[image]

My setup is : vscode , miktek 4.7 ,strawberry perl, windows 10

I am new in latex , I can not figure out how to build pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You called pdftex instead the needed xelatex or lualatex ...

Comment: @Mensch thanks , this  is cv template so I do not what should I edit to make it run , I am using LaTeX Workshop extension

Comment: I don't use VS Code or that plugin, but I gather from [this](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#magic-comments) that you can first enable magic comments, and then add a comment at the beginning of the file `% !TEX program = xelatex` and it will use `xelatex`. Or you can configure your own tools/recipes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `pdflatex file` call `xelatex file` or `lualatex file` as suggested by the `fontspec` package error message.